# Are new galaxies being formed and if so where?

Tags: galaxy

When asked this question the answers tend to be evasive, dwelling on the development of existing galaxies by absorption. Are there nearby proto-galaxies or gas clouds expected to form a galaxy sometime?

Comment: I think the short answer is no, but there's some nuisance as to what 'new' can mean, considering every other galaxy we see in the sky comes from the photons of galaxies from long, long ago.

Answer (score 6):

HSC J1631 + 4426 in the constellation Hercules at a distance of 430 million light years away is believed to be only 10 million years old, in terms of its star forming age.

If this estimation of its age is correct then it is likely that there are more protogalaxies in existence, although they will be very rare and hard to observe.

https://www.theregister.com/2020/08/02/ml_galaxy_spotting/